# if $a,b$ such $f(a+2b)+f(2a+b)>f(a)+f(b)$,show that $a+b<0$

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)$ be monotone decreasing function, if $a,b$,such
$$f(a+2b)+f(2a+b)>f(a)+f(b)$$

show that $a+b<0$

Comment: No, if $a=b=0$, $LHS=2f(0),RHS=2f(0)$.

Comment: @uniquesolution, if $a\neq b$ is it true?

Comment: Put $g(x)=f(a+x)+f(b+x)$. Then $g$ is monotone decreasing, and we have $g(a+b)>g(0)$. So $a+b<0$.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this condition can not hold for all pairs $a,b$.  If, for example, $b=-a$, the condition is impossible.

Comment: @lulu -- it is not required that the condition will hold for all pairs $a,b$.

Comment: I believe the OP did not say the condition is true for all $a,b$. OP merely wants a proof for the fact that if some $a$ and $b$ satisfy this then their sum must be less than $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $x=a+b$. If $x\geq 0$, then $x+b\geq b$ and $x+a\geq a$, and since $f$ is decreasing, $f(x+b)\leq f(b)$ and $f(x+a)\leq f(a)$, leading to $f(x+a)+f(x+b)\leq f(a)+f(b)$, i.e., to $f(2a+b)+f(a+2b)\leq f(a)+f(b)$.
The result follows.